# Hive Installation issues: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata

I'm trying to run Hadoop and Hive in a pseudo-distributed mode on my local machine. I've already got hadoop running but when I try to run Hive, it gives me the following error

```
`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/thrift/TException
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:266)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:149)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.thrift.TException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:321)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
    ... 3 more   `
```

I have tried to debug the problem but couldn't find what's missing.
My HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CLASSPATH are being set properly. Also, HADOOP_CLASSPATH contains libthrift-0.9.0.jar which has the class shown in the error above.

Any suggestion what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you set these properly? And make sure you have set these variables as well :

```
export HIVE_HOME=/path/to/your/hive/folder
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

To avoid yourself from these kinda problems use latest stable release of both Hadoop and Hive.

Comment: Yes, I have set all these variables in bashrc properly. These include HADOOP_HOME, HBASE_HOME, HIVE_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, HIVE_CONF_DIR, HIVE_CONF_DIR.

I downloaded a stable release of Hive, not sure about Hadoop because it's been a while since I downloaded Hadoop.

Comment: Have you added hive/lib to your path?

Comment: NO, but isn't it added automatically by the hive script? Also, do you mean the env variable $PATH? I don't understand why do we need to add it to PATH? But anyway, the hive script automatically includes all the jars in HIVE_LIB path into HADOOP_CALSSPATH.

Comment: Added where(to what)?Yes env variable PATH. You need to add it to PATH so that it is available on your "machine's" classpath. HADOOP_CALSSPATH is not sufficient all by itself.

Comment: Alright, I did that as well. But it didn't change the situation. I still get the same error. And this is how my bashrc file looks like right now.


export HADOOP_HOME="/home/kannu/Desktop/hadoop-1.0.4"
export HADOOP_PREFIX=$HADOOP_HOME
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_PREFIX/conf"
export HABSE_HOME="$HADOOP_PREFIX/hbase-0.94.8"
export HIVE_HOME="$HADOOP_PREFIX/hive/trunk/build/dist"
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf
export HIVE_LIB=$HIVE_HOME/lib
export PATH=$HADOOP_PREFIX/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HBASE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HIVE_HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HIVE_LIB:$PATH

Comment: Sorry, Stackoverflow doesn't allow new lines and hecne the content looks messy a bit.

Comment: Not an issue. These are the last few lines of my bashrc : export PATH=$PATH:~/cwp/43R1/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export HADOOP_HOME="/hadoop/projects/hadoop-1.0.4"
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
export HBASE_HOME=/hadoop/projects/hbase-0.94.4
export HIVE_HOME=/hadoop/projects/hive-0.9.0....And it works perfectly fine for me...Are you sure about the location of Hive inside your HADOOP_PREFIX?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't see any difference here.

Comment: Hey i'm so so sorry about my first comment. By that I actually meant hive/bin

Comment: You can remove the lib thing. Apologies for the mistake.

Comment: Yes, extremely positive about that. Well, I can just run "whereis hive" and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

you should enter the $HADOOP_HOME/conf,modify the"hadoop-env.sh"file.modify the line"export HADOOP_CLASSPATH=**$HADOOP_CLASSPATH**:/home/itcast/hadoop-1.1.2/myclass" like this.